# What is the Ubuntu package for Image Magick Wand Development?

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

What is the Ubuntu package for Image Magick Wand Development ?

Please help.

apt-get install ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `libmagickwand-dev`:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```